# program.exe on shared folder, way to close it?

Tags: winforms

Since searching on the NET I didn't find anything useful, I'm gonna ask here.

Here is my scenario:

1) I have a winforms project that is located on a Shared Folder, so other users can access it and use it. 
2) The problem comes when I try to compile my project while other users use it. It gives me this error "impossible to copy "obj\Debug\HR_AttrezzaturaVeicoli.exe" in "bin\Debug\HR_AttrezzaturaVeicoli.exe". the max limit of attempts has been made, that is 10. (Its literally translated I hope you understand the error) 
3) My question: Is there any way yo avoid this problem (like shut down the .exe that is running on the user PC) or something similar?

Thank you

Comment: As long as anybody has the file opened from the shared folder the file will be locked, thus not allowing you to override it. IIRC there is a way to manually force the lock of a file to be released in windows, though you'd have to do this everytime before you try to update the file, and you'll need the proper permissions to do this. I think the easiest solution to this would be to not run the application directly from a shared folder (if possible), have you considered using something like ClickOnce instead?

Comment: Ah so there is no workaround... I will try to see what is this ClickOnce

Comment: While you can't easily overwrite the exe that's being used, you can rename it. So you could add some prebuild commands that move the exe.